# NGRX - Actions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux, rxjs, ngrx

trying to get this ngrx `@Effect` to work with an http call.

```
  @Effect()
  loadPosts$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(post.ActionTypes.LOAD)
    .map(() => {
      return this.postService.get()
        .map(posts => {
          return new post.LoadSuccessAction(posts)})
        .catch(() => of(new post.LoadSuccessAction([])));
    })
```

If I swap in the following simple return it works

`return new post.LoadSuccessAction([['one'], ['two']])`

My `postService` `get` method is very simple

```
  get() {
    return this.http.get(`{this.API_PATH}/api/v1/en/posts?limit=10&offset=0`)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Not really sure what might cause this or where to look.

**EDIT**

`LoadSuccessAction` looks like this

```
export class LoadSuccessAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: any[]) { }
}
```

Comment: Use `switchMap` in your effect. At the moment, your effect is emitting an observable, not an action.

Comment: bingo, changing the first map to switchMap does the trick. Need to revisit rxjs to get to the bottom of this. If you can provide an answer with some insight I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your service's result is an observable and returning that from the `map` operator in your composed effect sees the effect emit an observable - not an action.

The ngrx store interrogates the observable for a `type` property and, not finding one, effects the error you have mentioned.

RxJS contains several operators that will 'flatten' mapped observables into the composed observable. And the one you likely want is [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap). The `switchMap` operator will subscribe to the returned observable and will emit its values into the composed observable's stream of values. Also, if another `LOAD` action occurs before a pending service call completes, the pending call's observable is unsubscribed and ignored - which is probably the behaviour you want.

If you don't want pending service calls ignored, you can use [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap).